# Maxscript, backburner rendering renderElements

Tags: networking, render, maxscript

I have made a script that takes files from directory, and sends them to backburner for network rendering. When I run the script it renders fine but without the render elements they dont show in the backburner monitor nor do they save.
If I open some of the files manualy and send them to render with backburner it works fine, but not with the script?
The render element is VrayAlpha, but I dont think it matters.

This is the code Im using

```
on btnRender pressed do
(
    outputFilesDir = textModelsOut.text + "*.max"
    toRender = getFiles outputFilesDir
    man = NetRender.GetManager() 
    man.connect #automatic "255.255.255.0"
    man.GetControl() 

    for s in toRender do 
    (
        renderModelPath =  getFilenamePath s  + filenameFromPath  s
        job = man.newJob file:renderModelPath
        job.Submit()
    )
    man.Disconnect()

)
```

And this is quote from maxscript documentation, it says that render element data will not be available but it will be processed.

> Jobs can not have maps included, and render element data will not be
>   available for submitted job but render elements will process
>   correctly. These problems are resent when submitting a job from a
>   file, but not when submitting the current scene.

Anyways my solution was to use **job.newJob()** to open each scene and submit the current scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always include your code (or at least some of it) so that we can check it for issues and test it our selves.

However, I usually use a struct called NetRenderAutomation, developed by Gravey.
You can find it here:

http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?f=98&t=1059510&page=1&pp=15

I haven't had any problems with it, and it is fairly easy to use, and you are even allowed to modify it, if you need some special features for your self.

Hope you can use the answer.
Else feel free to post some code, and I'll look into it.